# getting OutofMemory exception when loading new Activity?

Tags: android, android-image

I have one Activity and 4 tab Activities.In each tab activity i have gallery , grid layout when i am coming back from tab-activities to my main Activity i am getting outofMemory exception.In my all tab activities i have lot of images.I have strucked from 5 day .Please help me.Here my logcat is:

```
07-30 17:28:42.375: I/dalvikvm-heap(18784): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16384016-byte allocation
07-30 17:28:42.406: D/dalvikvm(18784): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 1K, 34% free 40614K/61511K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
07-30 17:28:42.406: 
E/dalvikvm-heap(18784): Out of memory on a 16384016-byte allocation.
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784): 
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41f726a0 self=0x41f5f018
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784): 
  | sysTid=18784 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075198032
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):  
 | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=219 stm=55 core=0
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784): 
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:592)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784): 
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
07-30 17:28:42.406:
 I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
07-30 17:28:42.406: 
I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3419)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3352)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:426)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:184)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-30 17:28:42.406: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at com.inventit.commentu.CommentU_Activity.onCreate(CommentU_Activity.java:182)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-30 17:28:42.416: I/dalvikvm(18784):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 17:28:42.416: A/libc(18784): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 18784 (ventit.commentu)
07-30 17:28:42.416: A/libc(18784): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x007d0000 (code=1), thread 18799 (ventit.commentu)
07-30 17:28:50.154: E/Trace(18971): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-30 17:28:50.154: D/ActivityThread(18971): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
07-30 17:28:50.154: D/ActivityThread(18971): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
07-30 17:28:50.154: D/ActivityThread(18971): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
07-30 17:28:50.294: D/dalvikvm(18971): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 76K, 23% free 16129K/20931K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
07-30 17:28:50.334: I/dalvikvm-heap(18971): Grow heap (frag case) to 40.043MB for 16384016-byte allocation
```

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Are you creating Bitmaps? Post your main activity code.

Comment: You're trying to allocate 16MB of memory.  What are you loading?

Comment: In my main activity I have background image ,buttons with background image and i have list with 30 emoticon images.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Managing Bitmap Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) article from developers site.

For API<=10:

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, using recycle() is recommended. If you're displaying large amounts of bitmap data in your app, you're likely to run into OutOfMemoryError errors. The [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) method allows an app to reclaim memory as soon as possible.
>
> Caution: You should use recycle() only when you are sure that the bitmap is no longer being used. If you call recycle() and later attempt to draw the bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap".
>
> The following code snippet gives an example of calling recycle(). It uses reference counting (in the variables mDisplayRefCount and mCacheRefCount) to track whether a bitmap is currently being displayed or in the cache. The code recycles the bitmap when these conditions are met:
>
> - The reference count for both mDisplayRefCount and mCacheRefCount is 0.
> - The bitmap is not null, and it hasn't been recycled yet.

For API>=11:

> Android 3.0 (API Level 11) introduces the [BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap) field. If this option is set, decode methods that take the Options object will attempt to reuse an existing bitmap when loading content. This means that the bitmap's memory is reused, resulting in improved performance, and removing both memory allocation and de-allocation.

Comment: for above API level 10?my app run from 2.2 above.

Comment: for the API >=10, there's also some notes to consider in the [abovementioned article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#inBitmap). If you are targeting API>=8, then you should consider using both approaches and define what exactly to use by checking API at runtime.

Comment: how i can check if my app running in which api level

Comment: `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` returns a current number of the device API. You can also use `Build.VERSION_CODES` constants to us version names instead of just number.